# Is there a practical alternative to .append?

Tags: javascript

I have been working all day to try and troubleshoot an issue.  I have a program that does an append of a string at the end of a table row.  However, for some reason I am not able to get at this string via Javascript.  I've tried the listener thing and for whatever reason the way this particular string is being created I just can't access is via the DOM.

This is essentially the line of code that's giving me trouble...

```
var delButtonHTML = '<a class="' + options.deleteCssClass + '" href="javascript:void(0)">' + options.deleteText +'</a>';
if (options.deleteContainerClass) {
} else {
    row.append(delButtonHTML);
```

It is creating the button, which is essentially an anchor....but I can't get to it no matter what I try in the DOM.  Is there an alternative to append that would work in this situation?  I've tinkered with update...and extend and no immediate luck.

Comment: I'm a bit confused if you are talking about JavaScript or Python.

Comment: My bad.  Too much time at keyboard.  Yep this is Javascript.

Comment: Are you thinking of `.appendChild()`? The argument has to be an element, not an HTML string.

Comment: If you use jQuery, it has `.append()`, and the argument can be HTML or an object.

Comment: Do you want to append a string or an element? If you want to append an element from HTML, use `row.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", delButtonHTML);` instead. Alternatively, use a proper element: `const delButton = Object.assign(document.createElement("button"), { value: options.deleteText }); delButton.classList.add(options.deleteCssClass);` and `row.append(delButtonHTML);`. Don’t use links that act as buttons; that’s bad practice and has a negative accessibility impact.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+html+string+%22.append%22+-jquery) of [Append html element to the DOM instead of string of html](/q/53746340/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.createElement`.

```
let a = document.createElement('a');
a.className = options.deleteCssClass;
a.href = 'javascript:void(0)';
a.textContent = options.deleteText;
row.appendChild(a);
// use the a variable to access the element
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I'll play with it a bit and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` requires a DOM element to be passed to it, not a string. So, instead of manually constructing a string, dynamically create a new element and configure it.

Also, you should not be using a hyperlink with `javascript:void(0)` because it's not 1997 any more. Any visible element supports a `click` event so just use something like a `span` and a `click` event. Hyperlinks are for navigation only and when you don't use them that way, it causes problems for visually impaired users who rely on screen readers.

```js
var delButton = document.createElement("span");
delButton.classList.add(options.deleteCssClass);
delButton.textContent = options.deleteText;

// Don't test for a condition where you aren't going to do anything
if (!options.deleteContainerClass) {
    row.append(delButtonHTML);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Trying to get it to work.